# making macros in ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-web-app

[image]

There is a Store list forms which contains Open Date, Store Number.

After the Open Date is updated, I want to open popups like below.

[image]

And If I click yes, I want to update the target date which has the same store number as in the Store list.
But I don't know how to connect the store number data from Store list to here.
I use ms access web app.

Comment: Maybe use SetValue macro action if you want to edit field of current record? What is 'Store list' - a combobox? Run a SQL UPDATE action with dynamic parameter that references the combobox?

Comment: "Store List" is a form which contains lots of data. I add the photos. Where is SetValue macro action or SQL UPDATE action? I can't find any??

Comment: I meant an SQL UPDATE action query object which would be run with OpenQuery macro action. Or use RunSQL macro action to execute an SQL statement. Click on "Show All Actions" on the macro design tab to reveal SetValue and RunSQL.

Comment: @June7 Seems like it is just for the desktop version..not for the web app..!

Comment: Unfortunate. I don't use macros and never built web app. Why save TargetDate? Can it be calculated when needed? What determines the target date?

Comment: @June7 I had the macro that will calculate the target date automatically,(DateAdd(Day,-([varOpenWeek])*7,[varOpenDate])). like this. I want to use this macro when the user says "yes". But seems like there is no way to bring the Open Date data at the store list to the new forms which is asking "Do you want to update the Target Date?".

Comment: Is this what TempVars are for? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5e8a3452-1d1e-4ab6-8d85-f17c641419cc/tempvars-in-access-2013-web-apps?forum=accessdev